# Next Auth.js To Interact with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-auth

I have a /pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js file with the following code:

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID || "",
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET || "",
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID || "",
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET || "",
    })
  ],
};

export default NextAuth({
  ...authOptions,
});
```

How can I make it to where I can run a MongoDB command to find user by email that it received from the social login and if the user isn't found, to create a user in my database? I have yet to find any documentation on this matter.  I basically want to run this code after a user signs in:

```
let user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!user) {
          user = await User.create({
            email,
            displayName,
            picture,
            provider,
            chatHistories: initialChatHistories,
          });
        }
```

With email, displayName, picture, and provider being taken from the sign in (name, email, picture from Facebook or Google) and then provider being google or facebook.